# How to serve a file not saved in folder, stored in postgresql database, and to be rendered to HTML by expressjs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, multer, node-postgres

We first sent the file to be posted as following:

```
router.post('/savefile', multer().single('filesource'), (q,s) => {  
     db.query("insert into filesource  (filerefid, source) values ($1, $2) returning filerefid",   [ q.body.filerefid,  q.file ])
      .then (r=> s.send(r.rows[0]))
  })
```

And then tried to show that as following to the HTML:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://localhost:3000/getsource/1"></object>
```

Which is  requested by:

```
router.get('/getsource/:i', (q,s) => {
      db.query('select source from  filesource  where  filerefid = $1;',
               [q.params.i])
        .then (r=> s.send(Buffer.from(r.rows[0].source.buffer)))
    
})
```

However the files cant be showed or downloaded correctly like that, What is the best way of doing that, without saving file in any directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are missing content type header in the response.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Also consider setting `Content-Disposition` header to present a correct file name.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"
```

*Update*

`file` property which is provided by multer is a js object, which contains `buffer` property with binary data of the file. In http get method this binary data should be returned decorated by the required http headers mentioned above.

Comment: did that, we still receive ambiguous binary cant be open, not sure is that because the way we insert it to the db or the way sent it back.

Comment: Try to save the binary into a file and then open it. If it can be opened, the problem is in the get endpoint.

Comment: Your `q.file` is an object, which contains binary data in the field `buffer`. In get method your have to return this binary data, not the js object. As I said before, check what is saved in the db, then decide if you need metadata fields like originalname, encoding, fieldname. In general to serve the pdf you need only the `q.file.buffer` content

Comment: well! tried to write the file as 
          fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/xyz.pdf', r.rows[0].source, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
          });

the file saved  not ok,

Comment: Thank you, for the notice

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Oleg Flores answer for correct header, and the notice in his comment, that we should use the buffer from the object, that in the case of not saving any file by Multer, values of the insert query should be

```
[ q.body.filerefid,  q.file.buffer]
```